# How to check collision on 2D map in SFML?

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d, collision-detection, sfml

I have one RectangleShape for wall and I draw this one object for every "1" on my 2D map:

```
int map[5][8] =
{
    { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
    { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
    { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
    { 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1 },
    { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
};

sf::RectangleShape player;
    player.setSize(sf::Vector2f(32,32));

    sf::RectangleShape wall;
    wall.setSize(sf::Vector2f(32,32));
    wall.setFillColor(sf::Color(40, 199, 40));

for (int mapX= 0; mapX< 8; mapX++)
        {
            for (int mapY= 0; mapY< 5; mapY++)
            {
                if (map[mapY][mapX] == 1)
                {
                    wall.setPosition(mapX * 32, mapY * 32);
                    window.draw(wall);
                }
}
}
```

And I checking for collision with code listed down, but this works for only last drawn wall. How to fix this? Theres only one object wall and I want to check collision for all drawned walls for my 2D array map.

```
if (event.type == sf::Event::TextEntered)
            {
                fPlayerY_t = fPlayerY;
                fPlayerX_t = fPlayerX;

                if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W)) fPlayerY_t = fPlayerY - 32;
                else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S)) fPlayerY_t = fPlayerY + 32;
                else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D)) fPlayerX_t = fPlayerX + 32;
                else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A)) fPlayerX_t = fPlayerX - 32;

                // temp pos
                player.setPosition(fPlayerX_t, fPlayerY_t);

                // collision with wall
                if (player.getPosition().x == wall.getPosition().x &&
                    player.getPosition().y == wall.getPosition().y)
                {
                    // back to prev position
                    player.setPosition(fPlayerX, fPlayerY);
                }
                else
                {
                    // No collision
                    fPlayerX = fPlayerX_t;
                    fPlayerY = fPlayerY_t;
                }
}
```

Comment: this may help you http://jsfiddle.net/singhiskng/rqr8abb8/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the coordinates of the player in array coordinates then check if `map[x][y] == 1`.
So do not have to loop through your entire map every game loop.
To convert into array coordinates, use `int` conversion :

```
int playerTileX = (int)(playerWorldX / 32);
int playerTileY = (int)(playerWorldY / 32);

if(map[playerTileX ][playerTileY ] == 1)
{
    // collision.
}
else
{
    // no collision.
}
```

What I dislike with this solution : it only checks for tiles collision, you have to be sure every wall is the same size (here 32*32).

Comment: What is playerWorldX and Y?

Comment: `playerWorldX` is the position of your player in world coordinate, corresponding to your `fPlayerX` or `fPlayerX_t`, while `playerTileX` is the corresponding tile on the map.